# Perl Text::Unidecode not producing correct output

Tags: perl

I am attempting to use `Text::Unidecode` to transform all accented characters (é,ç,è,à, etc) in a text file into their non accented counterparts (e, c, e, a, in this case). The function `unidecode()` should do just that, but I am getting strange output...

Each accented character seems to be replaced by 'A' followed by one or two other characters. For example, the input `"éèçàöôäüû"` produces the output `"A(c)A"ASSA APA'A$?A1/4A>>"`.

The function works fine if I use it on some user defined string in a script, but not when I use it in a while loop, like this:

```
#!/bin/usr/perl
use utf8;
use Text::Unidecode;
while(<>){
    print(unidecode($_));
}
#end
```

The problem persists with or without `use utf8;`, but could the text file format still cause issues? Is this a known issue with the module?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`use utf8` tells Perl what encoding you use in the source code. To set the encoding of the input, use

```
use open IN => ':encoding(UTF-8)', ':std';
```

Or, if you're not reading from a file, set the encoding of the *STDIN handle:

```
binmode *STDIN, ':encoding(UTF-8)';
```

See [open](http://p3rl.org/open) and [binmode](http://p3rl.org/binmode).

Comment: The "use open ..." solution worked, but not the binmode for some reason...

Comment: Because you're reading from the `*ARGV` handle, not `*STDIN`; but you can't set binmode on it, as it's not opened before you enter the loop.

Comment: @Whitehot, `binmode` does work as long as 1) you place it before the loop, and 2) you are actually reading from STDIN. `<>` is short for `<ARGV>` which only reads from `STDIN` when no arguments are provided. For example, it would work for `script <file`, but not for `script file`.

Comment: @Whitehot, `use open IN => ':encoding(UTF-8)', ':std';` does `binmode STDIN, ":encoding(UTF-8)"`, and it sets the default encoding for files opened in scope, so it works for both `script <file` and `script file`. In fact, you should use `use open ':encoding(UTF-8)', ':std';` to encode STDOUT too.

Comment: You can also simply decode each line from UTF-8 using [Encode](https://perldoc.pl/Encode#decode) or [Encode::Simple](https://metacpan.org/pod/Encode::Simple#decode_utf8), for example.